# May cp override subdirectories with the same name?

Tags: files, directory, cp

I downloaded an Adobe flash plugin,
It includes a `.so` file and a directory called `usr`.
In this folder, it has sub-folders like `bin`, `lib`,  `lib64`, `share`.
In the readme file, it says I need to do the following:

```
     sudo cp -r usr/* /usr
```

In the folder `/usr`, there are directories `bin`,`games`,`include`,`lib`,`local`,`sbin`, `share`, `src`.

I'm afraid that the command `sudo cp -r usr/* /usr` may override the subdirectories in `/usr`, and then cause problems.

Is my concern a real problem?

Comment: can you please explain what you intend to copy and what not?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `cp -r usr/* /usr`, do:

`cp -ri usr/* /usr`

The `-i` flag will make the copy process interactive and will ask your permission if it will overwrite any files. You will have an option either to grant or not to grant the permission.

P.S:- The version of `cp` on my test server is 8.4. It does not ask for permission before over-writing files unless I use `cp` with an `-i` flag. There is no alias set either. So the best way is to use the `-i` flag.

```
[sreeraj@server ~]$ cp --version
cp (GNU coreutils) 8.4

[sreeraj@server ~]$ cp -ir test testso
cp: overwrite `testso/test/offrandom'? y
[sreeraj@server ~]$ 

[sreeraj@server ~]$ cp -r test testso/
[sreeraj@server ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. It will only write over files that exists in both locations or copy new ones leaving old files in the destination alone.